# React: The best way to pass html attributes as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For instance, I want to behave a Button as a normal button and enhance the component.

```
<Button type="submit" className="btn">Click me!</Button>
```

leads to an html element:

```
<button type="submit" className="btn">Click me!</button>
```

Is there a way to write the Button component like this?:

```
const Button = ({children, ...htmlAttributesOnly}) => (
    <button {...htmlAttributesOnly}>{children}</button>
)
```

The idea behind is to make a component as flexible as possible by giving access to all of its html elements' attributes. Or do I have to repeat every html element attribute?

Comment: When you tried it did it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were really close to an answer, just wrap your props in curly braces:

```
const Button = ({ children, ...rest }) => (
    <button {...rest}>{children}</button>
)
```

Comment: What is the typescript equivalent for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Button component like this.

```
export default function Button(props) {
  return <button {...props}>{props.children}</button>;
}
```

Later you can use it like this.

```
  <Button onClick={()=>alert("hello")} style={{padding:10,border:'none',backgroundColor:'white'}} >Click Me</Button>
```